# Add stripe-cli into existing docker-compose configuration with enabled forwarding events

Tags: docker, docker-compose, stripe-payments

We can start stripe-cli from terminal using command:
`docker run --rm -it stripe/stripe-cli listen  --forward-to http://127.0.0.1:8080/stripe/webhook --api-key sk_API-KEY`

but how could I add this service to already existing docker-compose file, which works well both on localhost and in AWS? I want to hit a specific endpoint in `javaapp` whenever stripe-cli detects an event.

Example docker-compose file which should be extended:

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  https:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway

  javaapp:
    image: 1.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/JAVA_APP:${JAVA_APP:-latest}
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: -java.app.config=/etc/config.groovy
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/application/java/ExternalConfig.docker.groovy:/etc/config.groovy
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    profiles:
      - javaapp

  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.6-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - company-redis:/data

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6.12
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - company-mongo:/data/db/
      
volumes:
  company-mongo:
  company-redis:
```

Answer (score 0):

There's guidance for leveraging the Docker image of Stripe CLI in the README ([link](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli#docker)). You will likely need to adapt these steps to work with your docker-compose case, including the noted details about the password store.

Since you mentioned both local and hosted flows, note that this should only be required for local/non-publicly-accessible endpoints. If you're deploying to a public endpoint, you could instead leverage the Webhook Endpoints Create API ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/create)) to create a new endpoint for your new public endpoint as part of the deploy sequence, and if temporary then [delete it](https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/delete) when the endpoint is destroyed.